# Trying to look at interaction plot in emmeans - Error caused by missing argument in emmip?

Tags: r, emmeans

I'm following the vignette for examining interactions using emmeans here
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html

But I'm using my own dataset (all.det) - which does have significant interactions.
all.det contains 1621 observations of 12 variables, 3 of which are factors. 
I did try to create a re-producible example, but haven't figured out how to create one with all interactions significant. So I'm hoping this description will be enough for someone to point out where I am going wrong.

I am using

```
library(data.table)
library(car)
library(emmeans)
```

I run an anova using this code

DistanceKm is a numeric and Method, IDGroup and Sightability are factors.

```
model = lm(DistanceKm ~ Method * IDGroup * Sightability,
           data=all.det[(IDGroup == "Whale" | IDGroup == "Dolphin")
                        & DistanceKm <=5])
Anova(model, type="II")
```

All the interactions are significant, so I follow this up with an interaction plot as advised in the vignette

```
emmip(model, Method ~ Sightability | IDGroup)
```

But I get these errors

```
Error in if (!all(chk == tbl)) stop("Data appear to be randomized -- ",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : 
  Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed
```

I did try to create a subset of my data

```
sub=all.det[(IDGroup == "Whale" | IDGroup == "Dolphin") & DistanceKm <=5]
```

And then re-ran the model, followed with an Anova

```
model=lm(DistanceKm ~ Method * IDGroup * Sightability, data=sub)
Anova(model, type="II")
```

I get the same Anova results (as expected), but now I'm also able to produce the interaction plot without errors.

```
emmip(model, Method ~ Sightability | IDGroup)
```

I just get a single warning instead about a missing value

Am I missing something when calling emmip?

Comment: I am confused, because `all.det[(IDGroup == "Whale" | IDGroup == "Dolphin") & DistanceKm <=5]` would produce a subset of the *columns* of `all.det`. Don't you mean `all.det[(IDGroup == "Whale" | IDGroup == "Dolphin") & DistanceKm <=5, ]`?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I believe I'm selecting rows with the original code. I did try adding the comma in (would have been great if my problem were such a typo!), but get the same result. Both reduce the # of rows in my data table.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar warning, then found I had mislabled one of my factors in the dataframe. Check your dataframe and make sure there aren't any NA values where there shouldn't be.